# When I Click on Device Back Button app is closed

Tags: flutter, dart

When I click on the app bar back button it goes to the previous page. But when click on the device back button app is closed. Please tell me what will happen.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScopedModelDescendant(
      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child, MainModel model) {
        return WillPopScope(
          onWillPop: ()async{
            return true;
          },
          child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Add User Info'),
          ),
          body: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: _buildOrderForm(model),
          ),
        ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are already using `WillPopScope` which is good! However I see one thing that you have not properly implemented, which is:

```
onWillPop: ()async{
    return true;
},
```

You need to return a `Future` of `false` to disable the route being popped. See more info here:

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WillPopScope/onWillPop.html

> If the callback returns a Future that resolves to false, the enclosing
>   route will not be popped.

This should work:

```
onWillPop: () => Future<bool>.value(false),
```

Comment: Can you try it again? I added some other example `Future<bool>.value(false)`.

Comment: When I Click on a device back button app is closed and showing the below message in the terminal

Comment: D/ZrHung.AppEyeUiProbe(27886): stop checker.
W/libEGL  (27886): EGLNativeWindowType 0x78a0dfb010 disconnect failed
I/SurfaceView(27886): delay destroy surface control
W/libEGL  (27886): EGLNativeWindowType 0x78a0d92010 disconnect failed
I/SurfaceView(27886): need destroy surface control
D/ViewRootImpl[MainActivity](27886): surface should not be released

Comment: D/ActivityThread(27886): Remove activity client record, r= ActivityRecord{80c81d4 token=android.os.BinderProxy@c43b041 {com.restos.myrestos/com.restos.myrestos.MainActivity}} token= android.os.BinderProxy@c43b041
D/ZrHung.AppEyeUiProbe(27886): Current Activity:false
D/ZrHung.AppEyeUiProbe(27886): not watching, wait.
E/        (27886): [ZeroHung]zrhung_get_config: Get config failed for wp[0x0008]

Answer (score 1):

Method of the widget `WillPopScope` must be used as root

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: _onBackPressed,
      child: new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text(
            "On Back pressed",
            style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
        ),
        body: new Center(
          child: new Text("Home Page"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

In the above snippet, we have written a `_onBackPressed` method. It'll invoke when you back press from the mobile hardware button.